# d3.js Animation Follow Circles on Mouse Move

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, geometry

I'm using **d3.js** library and I'm having a problem implementing what the client needs.

Here's client request they want to "**black** circles to "**follow**" the mouse when you hover over it.

I don't know if d3.js library has this kind feature I can only see, on mouse drag.

I've added my sample code in JSFiddle see below:

```
node.on("mousemove", function(){
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    //node.attr('transform', 'translate(' + coords[0] + ',' + coords[1] + ')';
    nodes.call(force.drag); 
});
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/glenmongaya/4pjaeko3/5/

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a mouse-over to behave like a drag?

```
node.on("mousemove", function(d){
    d3.event.stopPropagation(); // stop the default event handling
    d.fixed = true; // fix the moused over node
    var coords = d3.mouse(this.parentNode); // get mouse position
    d.px = coords[0]; d.py = coords[1]; // set position
    force.resume(); // resume layout
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ljy9msg/).

Comment: Thanks, Mark it really helps me a lot. :)

Comment: Do you know how to set default order position of the circles? currently it's random
Ex : Circle 1, Circle 2 etc...

Comment: @GlenMongaya, give each datum an initial `x` and `y` parameter to control start position, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ljy9msg/64/)